# Где лучше всего хранить тестовые данные для модульных тестов?

Tags: юнит-тесты

Уже не первый день пишу модульные тесты, но постоянно сталкиваюсь с проблемой чтения модульных тестов спустя некоторое время.

Моя ситуация такова : не сложные по созданию тестовые данные пишу в виде внутренних констант-переменных. Но в последнее время натыкаясь на свой код вижу, что некоторые тесты в тестовом классе используют одни переменные, а другие методы другие тест-переменные.

Приведу пример:

```
class Authentication(unittest.TestCase):
    PASSWORD = 'super12345'
    INVALID_PASSWORD = 'wrong-password'

    def test_change_password(self):
        self.__add_user()
        old_password_hash = self.__get_password_hash()
        r = self.__send_password_change_request(self.PASSWORD, self.NEW_PASSWORD)
        data = json.loads(r.data)
        self.assertTrue(len(data)==0)
        self.assertNotEquals(old_password_hash, self.__get_password_hash())
        self.assertEquals(r.status_code, 200)

    def test_change_password_with_old_password(self):
        self.__add_user()
        old_password_hash = self.__get_password_hash()
        r = self.__send_password_change_request(self.PASSWORD, self.PASSWORD)
        self.assertEquals(r.status_code, 401)
        self.assertEquals(old_password_hash, self.__get_password_hash())
```

Как видно из кода двух тестов используются разный набор тестовых данных.

1. Допустимо ли такое?
2. Может имеет смысл тестовые данные вынести за пределы тестового
   класса?

Comment: Да, и в случае со сложными вещами (например, при тестировании распаковки архива), вы и не можете все данные запихнуть в тест. Однако в простых случаях стоит использовать дата-провайдеры (пусть и на один набор значений) - функции, возвращающие список из наборов данных для того или иного теста. В крайнем случае этот датапровайдер может обращаться ко внешнему функционалу для получения внешних данных. Строго говоря, то, что я написал, верно для PHP, но датапровайдеры, насколько знаю, в том или ином виде существуют для всех языков и тестовых фреймворков.

Comment: @Etki ОК. Спасибо. Но, что как организовать возврат различных тест-данных дата-провайдером, которые организованы в виде словаря из {username, password}? К примеру для одного метода один пароль, а для другого метода другой.

Comment: Два разных датапровайдера. Один `update_password_data_provider()`, второй `update_password_using_old_password_data_provider()`. При желании можно использовать для них общую базу, которую подтягивать из третьей метода или объявить свойством тестового класса.

Comment: @Etki: Вы можете уделить некоторое количество времени для код-ревью? Вот ссылка на тест-класс http://pastecode.ru/76cac/

Comment: @Etki: Можете преобразовать свой комментарий в виде ответа? И настоятельно рекомендую не писать ответы в виде комментариев!

Comment: Да, я отпишусь чуть позже и по примеру, и вообще

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сами по себе тестовые данные - довольно размытое понятие в том плане, что могут потребоваться вещи, которые вообще никак не запихнуть в код - например, системный тест автоматизированной системы обновления требует развернутое в файловой системе приложение и архив, который нужно распаковать. Такие вещи, конечно, хранятся снаружи теста, поэтому сама идея "хранить все внутри" не работает; я, например, храню целиковые ответы внешних апи в виде файлов с json для тех классов, которые занимаются разбором (nb: не получением, а разбором) этих структур.

Что до конкретных тестовых данных к каждому тесту - я привык оформлять их в виде *провайдеров данных* (*data providers*; в некоторых языках/фреймворках это называется *параметризованными тестами*) - эта концепция подразумевает, что для теста существует множество наборов данных, каждый из которых должен быть скормлен тестируемому функционалу, и для каждого из которых тест должен успешно пройти. В PHPUnit этот функционал доступен по умолчанию, для пакета `unittest` можно использовать [`unittest-data-provider`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest-data-provider), предоставляющий схожий функционал. После это остается только назначить каждому тесту свой провайдер, возвращающий интересующие наборы данных, и дело в шляпе. Подобный функционал практически обязателен для валидаторов, скажем, где есть заранее определенные массивы данных, которые нужно скормить и получить однозначное `true` / `false`.

По поводу конкретного теста: я пишу на PHP, и советы будут в основном по общей части.

Первое, что очень напрягло - доступ к глобальным переменным и БД. Если приложение создается прямо в тесте и не обстреливается запросами "снаружи", то базу данных лучше заменить на мок, это спасет время, защитит от лишней зависимости в тестах (развернутой БД) и спасет от тестирования драйвера базы данных, которым должен заниматься тест драйвера БД, а не тест приложения.

Дальше, что почти не напрягло - это вынос функционала в отдельные методы. у тестирования своя философия, которая не подразумевает циклов, условных конструкций, и предполагает, что один тест уже заключает в себе все, что нужно - он может пользоваться внещними инструментами, но его тело не должно быть размазано по другим методам. Когда тест валится, нужно быть уверенным, что а) завалился именно тест б) строчка (ассерт) завала точно известен в) это проблема именно в тестируемом функционале. Тест должен оборачивать этот функционал и в случае провала **явно сигнализировать, что именно сломалось**. На средних проектах это все не очень важно, но как только появляется отдел тестирования, пусть и в виде одного человека, все должно прочно стоять на рельсах (да и если тесты перейдут другому разрабу, они должны быть легкочитаемы). Какой-нибудь `__send_request()` я, вполне вероятно, оставил бы, но то, что там внутри заключены данные - это уже нехорошо. `__get_password_hash(self):` ровно так же должен принимать на вход `username`, по которому он ищет, иначе тест не знает, что именно он получает.

Но вообще я просто не люблю питон и придираюсь.

Comment: Про Python: Вы просто не умеете его готовить ;)

Comment: Думаю, что насчет "не люблю" - это все-таки от сердца